# Requested action class method runs twice on ajax call?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, struts2

I am using JQuery `getJSON()` method to get JSON data from server.
All is running fine but there is a little problem that my requested method called twice and I got similar values in my response JSON.

Javascript part:

```
$.getJSON( "getAgentDataAgentDetails", {campaign: campaign} , function(data) {
          var list = data.agentList;
          alert("Response : " + list.length);
      });
```

> alertbox returns : 'Response : 4'

struts mapping :

```
   <action name="*AgentDetails" method="{1}" class="com.contaque.monitor.AgentListAction">
        <result name="getAgentData" type="json"/>
    </action>
```

Action class method:

```
public String getAgentData(){
    System.out.println("Campaign : " + campaign);
    agentList.add(agnt1);
    agentList.add(agnt2);
    System.out.println("Agent List : " + agentList);
    return "getAgentData";
}
```

Java console O/P:

```
Campaign : avis
Agent List : [Agent{name=avis, extension=150, skill=English, phoneNumber=9876541230,status=INCALL, callType=IN, time=10:50:19}, Agent{name=sys, extension=857, skill=Hindi, phoneNumber=9658741235, status=WAITING, callType=OUT, time=08:40:16}]
Campaign : avis
Agent List : [Agent{name=avis, extension=150, skill=English, phoneNumber=9876541230, status=INCALL, callType=IN, time=10:50:19}, Agent{name=sys, extension=857, skill=Hindi, phoneNumber=9658741235, status=WAITING, callType=OUT, time=08:40:16}, Agent{name=avis, extension=150, skill=English, phoneNumber=9876541230, status=INCALL, callType=IN, time=10:50:19}, Agent{name=sys, extension=857, skill=Hindi, phoneNumber=9658741235, status=WAITING, callType=OUT, time=08:40:16}]
```

Comment: Where do you call getJSON? What is `agentList`?

Comment: @Ankit: Post your JSP.

Comment: What is the `AgentDetails` method?